# SSL verification error at depth 0: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, ssl-certificate

My company uses a proxy for all internet traffic for security reasons, but unfortunately this breaks SSL with Ruby.

When I try `gem install rake` or any other `gem` command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 0: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /C=US/ST=New York/L=New York City/O=My Company, Inc./OU=Corporate/CN=mycompany.com to your local trusted store
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      failed  ❌  (certificate verification)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: This is why [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)-style "security" proxies are actually really bad news for security.

Comment: Yeah, in addition to slowing down all traffic, they do make things unnecessarily hard in situations like these. A slightly more naïve (or lazy) user may have disabled the SSL check altogether because that's so much easier. Really bad idea for security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means ruby can't find a valid certificate, so you need to add one.

**TLDR**: Add your SSL certificate to the PEM file. This fix may work for other applications where SSL verification is failing, as many use the same PEM file. The PEM file is a lookup full of hashes corresponding to trusted certificates, and if any of the certificates along the network path are missing SSL validation will fail.

### 1. Get SSL Certificate hash for the address in the error message

The error specifies the address of the server, in this example `mycompany.com`. Navigate to this address in a web browser. I used Google Chrome. It may redirect, but that's okay. You should see a lock icon to the left of the web address in the address bar, indicating that the connection is secure. This means the browser has found the SSL certificate. To get the hash, click on the lock icon to open the certificate viewer. Click on the "Details" tab, make sure to select the top level certificate (this should match the original web address you got in the error message) then click "Export". Save the file somewhere and open it in a text editor and you will see the hash.

[image]
[image]

Opening the file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIESzCCAzOgAwIBAgIJAKNiDFgr+nN4MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG7MQswCQYD
VQQGEwJVUzERMA8GA1UECAwITmV3IFlvcmsxFjAUBgNVBAcMDU5ldyBZb3JrIENp
[lots more stuff...]
Z05JMrKlVndAmcLUoycD2hGqY9I1/9atfV23MkNslR+LBo7nMbjUj+lk/1rchww=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

### 2. Locate Ruby's certificate file and append the server's certificate

In a terminal, run:
`ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'`

You'll see a path. In my case:
`"C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/etc/ssl/cert.pem"`

Open this file in your text editor and add append the certificate to the end. Probably a good idea to add a comment specifying what the certificate is for. Leave a newline above and below the entry to be safe:

```
mYCOMPANY.com
====================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[paste certificate hash here]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save the file. At this point you may be able to skip the next step.

### 3. Tell Ruby to use the file (may be optional)

In PowerShell:

`$env:SSL_CERT_FILE="C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\etc\ssl\cert.pem"`

In Command Prompt:

`set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\etc\ssl\cert.pem`

### 4. Test it

Run [this script](https://github.com/rubygems/ruby-ssl-check/blob/master/check.rb) to check whether your errors are resolved. Follow the link, save it as `check.rb`, and run `ruby check.rb`. You should see something like this:

```
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           3.2.2p53 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c05aa65cbf203442d37fef7c12390015) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
RubyGems:       3.4.10
Bundler:        2.4.10
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
Loaded version: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
SSL_CERT_FILE:  C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/etc/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/etc/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       success ✅
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      success ✅
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: success ✅

Hooray! This Ruby can connect to rubygems.org. You are all set to use Bundler and RubyGems.
```